# Write size of a byte array (C# winforms)

Tags: c#

I am writing some content to a binary file. one item is an image, so converting image in to a byte array and writing it as below.

```
 BinaryWriter bw = (BinaryWriter)writer;
 WritePropertyTag(property); //IMAGE_TAG
 bw.Write((short)(sizeofshort + imagedata.Length + (writesize ? sizeofshort : 0)));
 if (writesize)
 {
     bw.Write((short)(imagedata.Length));
 }
 bw.Write(imagedata);
```

and reads it back with the below code:

```
short datasize = binReaderIn.ReadInt16();
byte[] data = new byte[datasize];
binReaderIn.Read(data, 0, datasize);
Image img = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(data));
```

The above works very well if the byte array is relatively smaller (Short numbers).

When we want to store larger images (with approx byte array size 25k) it fails. I tried using long instead of short in the above code blocks and read with ReadInt64() method, but not getting the right size. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please show the actual code with `long`.

Comment: replaced "sizeofshort" with 8

Comment: In both places?

Comment: what is the error, when you say it *fails*

Comment: I replaced short with long everywhere, and reads using ReadInt64() method. Not getting any error but the array size is getting a very large number, not the data size saved.

Comment: (Aside) There's no point in using a `long` to represent the image size because the array cannot exceed 2GB in size. You can just use `int` (AKA `Int32`).

Comment: I tried with "Int", I guess the size of int is 4 and ReadInt32() should work, right? but still giving wrong size!

Answer (score 0):

```
BinaryWriter bw = (BinaryWriter)writer;
WritePropertyTag(property);
bw.Write((uint)(sizeofshort + data.Length + (writesize ? sizeofshort : 0)));
if (writesize)
{
   bw.Write((uint)(data.Length));
}
bw.Write(data);
```

Using uint instead of short solved the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).